# HTML CSS Control a DIV from another DIV

Tags: html, css

I wonder know how to change a DIV from another DIV in the CSS

I mean : I have 2 div, and when the mouse is over 1 div, I want change the CSS of the other DIV

Thanks you

HMTL :

```
<li id="aboutUs">
 <a>
  <div id="icon"></div><h1>ABOUT US</h1>
  <p id="nav">
     A bit about us, jackpots, good gaming & join the community
  </p>
 </a>
</li>
```

CSS :

```
#aboutUs{
float:left;
border-right: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231);
border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(231, 231, 231); /* gray color */
height: 78px;
padding-top: 20px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
vertical-align: top;
min-height: 62px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
color:#808080; /* #808080; */
cursor: pointer;
}

#aboutUs:hover{
border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(86, 126, 1); /* green color */
}

li a{
color:#808080; /* Color 2 */
}

li a:hover{
color: #000000; /* Color 1 */
}
```

I WANT TO BLEND THE "ABOUT US" and the "li a" for some COLLSION DETECTION's REASON with the mouse. I want that when the mouse is hover the "about us, the "li a hover's css execute"

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML source?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible in CSS (although I could easily be wrong). At the very least, it would be easier to use some JavaScript.

Comment: please paste some code.

Comment: @pjp look I 've paste some code and explaination..

Comment: Based on your HTML you would need to use: `#aboutUs:hover > a {}` so that the link is styled when you hover over its parent, the list-item.

Comment: @Adrift Doesn't work... Or maybe I wrote it wrong... I want to execute the "a:hover's css" and the "aboutUs:hover's css" when the mouse is hover the aboutUs.

Comment: @user2372006: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mpa5k/

Comment: @Adrift No, you are on the good way, but It's the "li a" not "a", it doesn't work with the "li a" for me ... I want execute the "li a:hover"'s css.

Comment: @Adrift Maybe I wrote my HMTL code wrong.. But I want change the color of the <p> only.. Can you do it for me ?

Comment: Well in that case you can use: `#aboutUs:hover p {color: red;}` - http://jsfiddle.net/mpa5k/1/ ... like this right?

Comment: @Adrift write the answer then I ll can Set the topic as Solved and give you +Rep

Comment: I already have .. look below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two elements are siblings you can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), e.g.

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

---

```
div {
background: slategray;
height: 5em;
width: 5em;
}

div + div {
background: lightgray;
}

div:hover + div {
background: peru;
border-radius: 10px 50px / 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5fgT/1/

Or if the elements are siblings but not *immediate* siblings, you can use the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators):

http://jsfiddle.net/b5fgT/3/

You can also style a descendant element when mousing over its parent:

```
div:hover > div {
/* CSS */
}
```

Edit as per your comment: *"But I want change the color of the `<p>` only.. Can you do it for me?"*

Well in that case you can use: `#aboutUs:hover p {color: red;}` - http://jsfiddle.net/mpa5k/1

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is a bit tricky. Css does not currently travel UP the Dom, only DOWN the Dom. If you are traveling down, you can simply use the + for adjacent siblings, or ~ for general siblings selector.

Or, you could give them the same class name and use the :not:hover pseudo class. Check out this fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LGQMJ/

```
div:not(:hover) span.question {
    opacity: 0; 
}
div:hover span.question {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

If I could see your HTML structure I could help you more.

Comment: You will need to post your HTML as well